# For each loop does not work as expected if I use the list directly from a map

Tags: java, foreach, linked-list

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedList> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedList>();

for(Map.Entry<Integer,LinkedList> entry : myMap.entrySet()){

    /*Does Not Work- Incompatible Object Type */               
    for(Integer temp : entry.getValue()){
         arr[i] = temp;
         i++;
    }

    /* Works Fine */
    LinkedList<Integer> templist = entry.getValue();
    for(Integer temp : templist ){
         arr[i] = temp;
         i++;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of your `LinkedHashMap` is a raw type - `LinkedList`. Change it to a generic type - `LinkedList<Integer>`.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {            
    for(Integer temp : entry.getValue()) {
        arr[i] = temp;
        i++;
    }
}
```

This way the compiler knows that `entry.getValue()` is a `LinkedList<Integer>`, so iterating over that `LinkedList` must return `Integer`s and not any `Object`s.